# Animating ui-view without position:absolute

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router, animate.css

I have the following structure in my Angular app:

```
<header></header>
<section>
    <div ui-view></div>
</section>
<footer>
```

Where my `ui-view` uses [animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to bounce in and out of the screen. My problem is that during animation I get two instances of `<div ui-view>` on top of each other, pushing the first instance down. All of the examples I can find get around this by using `position: absolute` but since I don't know the height of the `ui-view` in advance **and** have a `<footer>` below my `<div ui-view>` which I need to display, I can't use this.

This is the way I want the animation to work, except the `<footer>` needs to appear *below* the content:

http://jsfiddle.net/9rjrdd1q/

How can I achieve this without `position: absolute`? Or at the very least, get my `<footer>` to display...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, I just made a workaround using a directive which resizes the parent container to the height of the `ui-view` every time the state changes:

```
myApp.directive("fixPositionAbsolute", ["$document", "$window", function($document, $window) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function($scope, element) {
            // Flag to determine if the directive has loaded before
            var hasLoaded;
            // DOM representation of the Angular element
            var domElement = element[0];
            $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
                console.log(domElement);
                // Get the computed height of the ui-view and assign it to the directive element
                domElement.style.height = $window.getComputedStyle($document[0].querySelector("[ui-view]")).height;
                // After the first height change, add a class to enable animations from now on
                if(!hasLoaded) {
                    domElement.classList.add("auto-height");
                    hasLoaded = true;
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then added an animation for the `content-wrapper`'s height so that it *moves* along with the bounce animation:

```
#content-wrapper.auto-height {
    height: 0;
    transition: height 0.6s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxhn1csc/)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could remove `position:absolute` and apply this css rule:

```
[ui-view].ng-leave {
    display:none;
   -webkit-animation: bounceOutLeft 1s;
}
```

But the leaving div will get hidden immediately:

Check the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9rjrdd1q/1/)

Comment: I really would like to leave the `bounceOutLeft` in tact if possible