# Change element height on animation start (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've set up a transition that slides between my views, like so: https://plnkr.co/edit/yhhdYuAl9Kpcqw5tDx55?p=preview

I need to set the view position to absolute in order to make the two 'panels' slide together, but my issue is that my view container defaults to a height of 0 due to the absolute positioning. What I would like to do is to get the view's height immediately when the animation starts, and change the outer container's height to match it, but I'm running into a couple of problems - I don't know how to actually get that element's height, and I am unsure how to do it upon the animation start.

So far i've tried copying other people's work and have created a directive with a link function that has the element passed to it, but my method of "querySelector" just returns null.

```
myApp.directive('viewContainer', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          containerHeight: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess", function() {

                //scope.height = element[0].querySelector('#view-box').offsetHeight;

                //scope.containerHeight.height = scope.height;
            });
        },
        template: "<div id='view-box' ng-view></div>"
    };
});
```

I'm also using `scope.$on("$locationChangeSuccess"...)` but I don't actually know if this is the correct way to get whether the animation has started/ended. Could anyone give me some insight as to how I could accomplish this? I've tried looking at a similar situation here:
[Animating ui-view without position:absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074558/animating-ui-view-without-positionabsolute)
but I couldn't find any documentation on `$stateChangeSuccess` and I wasn't really sure what he was doing here.

Thanks for the help, it is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out by cheating a little bit:

- `element[0].querySelector('#view-box').offsetHeight;` was not working, i believe because the view coming in was not yet created. I cheated by adding a $timeout and then using `element[0].querySelector('.ng-enter').offsetHeight`, which now gets the entering view height which I can pass to the ng-style in my container.
- `$locationChangeSuccess` works fine as a location change event, but does not let me know when an animation finishes. This is actually fine because I realized I don't need to know when the animation finishes.

If anyone can figure out a better way of doing this without using a timeout, I would love to hear it. Thanks!